# Using LAMP architecture

Tags: debian, lamp

I want to use a LAMP architecture. I am currently using WAMP for PHP. How to install Linux in partition with Windows Vista? Can annyoone reply? Also I am going to use Debian 6. Is Debian good for using with LAMP. I am going to use LAMP for coding purpose only. I am hosting the site on another server. Should I switch to LAMP?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Debian has the packages to run Apache, MySQL and PHP. This is probably not the forum to hunt down install advice for dual-booting.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.ghacks.net/2008/12/14/how-to-dual-boot-windows-vista-and-linux/

http://www.pronetworks.org/forums/how-to-dual-boot-windows-vista-and-linux-t78184.html

and in any case, best is to reinstall vista, set partitions in the beginning ! after installing vista first, there is a way of installing linux debian e.g. via windows into its partition, from then on during startup u can choose which one to boot / use . .  e.g.

for the installation of debian via diff OS and diff partition use this link 
http://www.debian.org/devel/debian-installer/

even though it might be wrong forum, that was a plain answer earlier an nonconstructive, then he should at least give a link to a better forum